# How to handle sites that avoid scrapping from headless browser with Playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I want to scrap some data from a National Bank with the next script:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from loguru import logger

# Function that extracts the data from the Bank of Colombia
def main():
    with sync_playwright() as pw:
        # I create the browser to interact with the page:
        browser = pw.chromium.launch(headless=True)

        # Login on the website:
        banco_central_col = browser.new_page()
        banco_central_col.set_default_timeout(240000)
        logger.info(f"'Entering the page -------> Tasa Representativa del Mercado (TRM - Peso por dólar) | Banco de la República'")

        banco_central_col.goto('https://www.banrep.gov.co/es/estadisticas/trm')
        logger.info(f"Successful Entry")
        the_html = banco_central_col.locator("//html").inner_html()
        logger.warning(the_html)
        # logger.info(f"Entering the page -------> '{banco_central_col.title()}'")

        # From here I enter the section of the exchange rate:
        with browser.new_page() as tasa_de_cambio:
            logger.info("My last headless point unfortunately :_(")
            # Taking a screenshot to verify the last connection point:
            banco_central_col.screenshot(path="screenshot.png", full_page=True)

            banco_central_col.locator("//html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[6]/main/section/div/section[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/span/a").click(timeout=240000)
            logger.info(f"Clicking on the link 'Serie histórica para un rango de fechas dado (desde 27/11/1991)'")
        new_page = tasa_de_cambio.value
        new_page.wait_for_load_state()
        logger.info(f"Entering the page -------> '{new_page.title()}'")
```

When I run the code with the browser visible everything runs just fine, but when I switch to headless mode the site activates some kind of anti-bot protection.

I noticed so, because debugging the code I took the html to take a look of what the problem was and I did a screenshot to the last point that my headless browser could connect. And this is the last point my code could enter:
[image]

***NOTE*: In case you wonder, when the site is sucessfully connected, this is what I should watch and the selected area is what I am looking for, I want to click the link and proceed to scrap the data I need:**

[image]

You can check and run the code by yourself, this is just for scrapping reasons, it is free to go.

If needed, my dependencies are:

```
python = "^3.10"
playwright = "^1.27.1"
loguru = "^0.6.0"
```

Comment: It is me or the page where you have to be redirected is down? Maybe is because I am not in colombia? I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking your time trying it out. I stopped testing for today, but it wouldn't surprise me if it is down. The site is not quite optimized. And answering your doubt, there should not be a problem for you not being in Colombia, because neither I am.